# Features activated for a page

Tags: feature-activation, features

Are there any features activated or deactivated for different pages like Wiki Page, SharePoint Page or Web Part page in SharePoint? Or the features are relevant only for the sites and not pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question, are the features are relevant only for the sites and not pages?

- As a short answer Yes, it's a Web / Site scope.
- Generally, the feature is activated at Farm / Web Application /  Web /  site collection scope.

Check also [Listing All SharePoint Server 2013 Features – Including Name, Title, Scope, ID and Description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/razi/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-server-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description/)

Comment: can u create a chat link again?

Comment: Check this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44270/room-for-m-qassas-and-tushar-anand